# navigate not working ONLY for empty fragment after enabling pushState

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, backbone.js, marionette, pushstate

So, I had a Backbone Marionette app fully working with hashes. Then, I decided to enable pushState for better UX URLs.

I access the app at:

```
http://localhost:8888/multikanban/app
```

I applied the following changes:

1. Enable pushState

   ```
   Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/multikanban/app/"});
   ```
2. Define the following .htaccess

   ```
   <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
       RewriteRule (.*) app/index.html [L]
   </ifModule>
   ```

At this point, the app loads without issues, I can move around, login, etcetera. However, when App.navigate("") is called (when I need to go to the initial app state) I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

landing_app.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showLanding' of undefinedlanding_app.js:15 (anonymous function)require.js:1658 context.execCbrequire.js:874 Module.checkrequire.js:1121 (anonymous function)require.js:132 (anonymous function)require.js:1164 (anonymous function)require.js:57 eachrequire.js:1163 Module.emitrequire.js:925 Module.checkrequire.js:1151 Module.enablerequire.js:782 Module.initrequire.js:1178 callGetModulerequire.js:1572 context.completeLoadrequire.js:1679 context.onScriptLoad

require.js:1903 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/multikanban/scripts/apps/landing/show/show_controller.js".
```

With App.navigate("") I am only updating the URL, nothing should be being "transferred" as the error states...

Observations:

1. The App.navigate("") worked before using pushState.
2. Changing App.navigate("") to something like App.navigate("a") makes it work but ofcourse the URL is wrong..
3. Commenting the App.navigate("") doesnt get the app to crash, it simply doesn't update the URL, so yeah the problem should be with App.navigate("")

How can I get App.navigate("") to work? Why is that command apparently interacting with the server, shouldn't it just update the URL and history? Any ideas of where could I ask about this?

Comment: have you tried - `App.navigate('/');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of struggling I fixed it. Apparently, it had nothing to do with the latter changes, but with the requirejs configuration, which had been mysteriously working for the last month :D

I changed the data-main and src in the index.html from

```
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script data-main="/multikanban/app/scripts/main.js" src="/multikanban/app/scripts/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Also, make sure to define the absolute path in the href for styles if you have any.

Cheerio!

Thanks @jdaudier for the help

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting seems to indicate that requirejs is not mapping correctly to your designated path.

Comment: If I comment App.navigate("") it works, the show_controller.js gets loaded and shows what it has to show. The URL doesn't update then. Which confuses me, should App.navigate("") just be updating the URL and the history? why does it affect anything else?